# Actionscript 3 drag and drop multiple objects to target with well done

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

The drag and drop works, however, I have no idea how to create an if statement that goes to the next scene when all movieclips have been placed on the target.

I've tried placing the instance names in an if statement with the hittestobject however, no luck.

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

/* Touch and Drag Event
Allows the object to be moved by holding and dragging the object.
*/
var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

var lemons:Array = [lemon1_mc, lemon2_mc, lemon3_mc, lemon4_mc, lemon5_mc];

for each(var lemonMC:MovieClip in lemons)
{
    lemonMC.buttonMode = true;
    lemonMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pickobject);
    lemonMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, dropobject);

    lemonMC.startX = lemonMC.x;
    lemonMC.startY = lemonMC.y;    
}
var fl_DragBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);    

function pickobject(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x; 
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;       
}

function dropobject(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_mc)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;
        event.target.visible = false;           
    } else {
        event.target.x = event.target.startX;
        event.target.y = event.target.startY;
        event.target.buttonMode = true;
    }   
}

var melons:Array = [melon1_mc, melon2_mc, melon3_mc, melon4_mc, melon5_mc, melon6_mc, melon7_mc];
for each(var melonMC:MovieClip in melons)
{
    melonMC.buttonMode = true;
    melonMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pickobject2);
    melonMC.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, dropobject2);

    melonMC.startX = melonMC.x;
    melonMC.startY = melonMC.y;    
}
var fl_DragBounds2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

function pickobject2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    event.target.startTouchDrag(event.touchPointID, false, fl_DragBounds2);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x; 
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;       
}

function dropobject2(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_null)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;
        event.target.visible = false;           
    } else {
        event.target.x = event.target.startX;
        event.target.y = event.target.startY;
        event.target.buttonMode = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ever?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a counter that is equal to number of objects to drag, then every time you drop object (and detect if it was on target) you decrements the counter and at the end of the function you check if it's 0?

Comment: `var counter:Int = lemons.length + melons.length;`

Then after you do: `event.target.visible = false;` just `counter--;` and check if it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to remove your lemons/melons from their arrays when they pass the hit test.  Then check if each array is empty and continue to the next scene should that be the case.

You can actually reduce redundant code and use the same function (dropobject) for both lemons and melons.

```
function dropobject(event:TouchEvent):void {
   //Figure out which array this belongs to (is it a lemon or a melon)
   var array:Array; //the array the dropped item belongs to
   var hitMC:MovieClip; //the hit object for the lemon or melon

   if(lemons.indexOf(event.currentTarget) > -1){ //if the lemon array contains the currentTarget
       array = lemons;
       hitMC = target_mc;
   }else{
       array = melons;
       hitMC = target_null; 
   }

   if(event.currentTarget.hitTestObject(hitMC)){
        event.currentTarget.buttonMode = false;
        event.currentTarget.x = hitMC.x;
        event.currentTarget.y = hitMC.y;
        event.currentTarget.visible = false;

        //remove the item from it's array
        array.removeAt(array.indexOf(event.currentTarget));

        //check if there are any items left
        if(lemons.length < 1 && melons.length < 1){
            //both arrays are empty, so move on
            play(); //or however you want to move on
        }
   }
}
```

Getting more advanced, a better way to do this would be to make a base class for your lemons, melons and anything else you want to drag in the future.  Then you can add the dragging functionality into that base class and add properties for the hit target and an event for when it's hit it's target.   This would give you one code base that can be easily applied to any library object.